# Cache php output in static html

Tags: javascript, php, html, caching

I want to cache the output of a php script in static html. Have tried several guides and code examples but without success.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$cachefile = 'cached_php.html';
$cachetime = 18000;

if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
    include($cachefile);
    exit;
}
ob_start();
?>

<html>
    <script src="/feeds/phpscript.php"></script>
</html>

<?php
$fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
fclose($fp);
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

But all I get is the cached_php.html with the Content:

```
<html>
    <script src="/feeds/phpscript.php"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: What else did you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

Were you expecting phpscript.php to run?

If so you need to include the script rather than output it to the file:

```
<html>
    <?php include "/feeds/phpscript.php"; ?>
</html>
```

the `<script>` tag is for client side scripts and as such does not work with php as a src value.

Answer (score 0):

sry for bad description.

the phpscript.php loads lots of data out of the database into a table. this procedure takes ~5-10sek

i want to cache this output to a static html file